# Problem in storing splitted strings in attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, string

[image]

I want to split strings of column 'Text' and save them in column 'Text_edit'. So far the split and storing the new values in a new column works. However as can be seen in the attached figure, only the last value seems to be stored in every feature of the second column.

I aparently have a problem in my code for storing the strings in the new column.

Below my code:

```
 #example string to be splitted: {\fArial|b0|i0|c0|p34;\C6;A1 (ab GOK)}  
 #split output => A1 (ab GOK)     


        b.dataProvider().addAttributes([ QgsField("Text_edit", QVariant.String) ])
        b.startEditing()
        
        for f in b.getFeatures():
             split1 = feature['Text'].split(";")
             split2 = split1[-1]
             split3 = split2.split("}")
             split_final = split3[0]
             newval = split_final
             f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex('Text_edit'), newval)
             b.updateFeature(f)
            
        b.updateFields()
        
        iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(b,False)
```

Comment: i think you need to change `split1 = feature['Text'].split(";")` with `split1 = f['Text'].split(";")`
without knowing your entire code, i can't be sure but it sure won't work as is

Comment: Thanks a million it's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also advice to go easy on the .split() and maybe use a single regular expression regex, and do all your modifications inside with edit which replaces startEditing and stopEditing.
But your code works fine otherwise, this way is just somewhat cleaner

```
import re
from qgis.core import edit

#example string to be splitted: {\fArial|b0|i0|c0|p34;\C6;A1 (ab GOK)}  
#split output => A1 (ab GOK)     
    
with edit(b):
    b.addAttribute(QgsField("Text_edit", QVariant.String))
    pattern = re.compile(r".*;(.*)}")
    for f in b.getFeatures():
        newval = pattern.match(f['Text']).group(1)
        f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex('Text_edit'), newval)
        b.updateFeature(f)
    b.updateFields()
```